# Boolean not being saved properly in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript

I'm using the boolean `darkmode` to store whether or not the user has enabled dark mode. You click a button to enable it, which runs the `dark()` function. On each new page, I run an if/else to check whether it is on and apply the dark mode class to the document. Here's the code for the function:

```
function dark() {
          var element = document.getElementById('document');
          element.classList.toggle("dark");
          darkmode = !darkmode;
          sessionStorage.setItem('darkmode', darkmode)
 }
```

And for the if/else statement:

```
var darkmode = Boolean(sessionStorage.getItem('darkmode'));

if (darkmode == true) {
         document.getElementById('document').classList.add("dark");
}else if (darkmode == false){
         document.getElementById('document').classList.remove("dark");
}
```

And for the CSS class:

```
.dark,
.dark * {
     background-color: #222;
     color: #e6e6e6;
     border-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

And here's the HTML for the on/off button:

```
<i onclick="dark()"class="fas fa-moon"></i>
```

Please can anyone help? I'm sorry if I included irrelevant information.

EDIT: The issue is that when I go to a new page on light mode, dark mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function dark() {
              var element = document.getElementById('document');
              element.classList.toggle("dark");
              let darkmode = true // here you need to explicitly declare the variable
         
              localStorage.setItem('darkmode', darkmode)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is cleared when the page session ends.

If you want to store a setting, better use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead.